# How to display text from simple txt file in one column using DocumentFlowReader in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using DocumentFlowReader to display text from txt file. Everything is working fine, but when I go full screen my text split in several columns, how to display it only in one?

Here is my code:

XAML file:

```
<DockPanel>
            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <MenuItem Header="_File">
                    <MenuItem x:Name="OpenFile" Header="_Open" Click="OpenFile_Click" />
                    <Separator />
                    <MenuItem Header="_Exit" />    
                </MenuItem>      
            </Menu>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtCurrentPage" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" TextAlignment="Center" Background="LightYellow">
                Current page:
            </TextBlock>
            <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top">Your books</TextBlock>
                <ListView DockPanel.Dock="Left" x:Name="listboxBooks" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" PreviewMouseDoubleClick="listboxBooks_PreviewMouseDoubleClick">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Finished" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding readBook}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </DockPanel>

            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="Bisque">
                <Button x:Name="btnPreviousPage" Click="btnPreviousPage_Click" >Previous Page</Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnNextPage" Click="btnNextPage_Click">Next Page</Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnSavePage" Click="btnSavePage_Click" >Save Page</Button>
            </TextBlock>
            <FlowDocumentReader Name="FlowDocReader" Background="LightBlue">

            </FlowDocumentReader>
        </DockPanel>
```

This is how I read the text from file:

```
// Create OpenFileDialog 
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

// Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
dlg.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";

string filename = dlg.FileName;

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

paragraph.Inlines.Add(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename));

FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);

FlowDocReader.Document = document;
```

This code is doing ok, it is reading the data and displaying it, but when the window is full screen it displays the text in several columns. I want to display it in only one, even when the window is full screen. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the ColumnWidth property large enough for the screen.

```
FlowDocument document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
document.ColumnWidth = 2000; //or carefully calculate a proper value
FlowDocReader.Document = document;
```